# Get word in betwen first and last of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

my problem is to get word in between first and last of a string for example  string st="abcdefghi" and my problem is to get only def

Comment: You'll have to explain how you intend to determine what part of the string you want to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substring between first 3 and last 3 chars

```
string substring=str.Substring(3,str.Lenghth-6)
```

Comment: thanks you so much ,works